# Cardinality of cartesian products of a series of infinite sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $\hat P(A)=P(A)-\{\emptyset\}$, and $A_0=\mathbb{N}$ and $A_{n+1}=\hat P(A_n)$.

I was asked to prove $|A_n|=|A_n\times A_n|$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I thought about using induction: We have a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ so the statement holds for $A_0$.

Assume it holds for all $k < n$, we have :

$$|A_n|=|\hat P(A_{n-1}) \times \hat P(A_{n-1})|\space \space definition$$
And 
$$|A_{n-1}|=|A_{n-1} \times A_{n-1}| \space \space inductive \space assumption$$
So :
$$|P(A_{n-1})\times P(A_{n-1})|=|A_{n-1}\to\{0,1\}\times A_{n-1}\to\{0,1\}|=2^{|A_{n-1}|}2^{|A_{n-1}|}=2^{2|A_{n-1}|}=^{(*)}2^{|A_{n-1}|}=|P(A_{n-1})|$$
(*) - by the induction assumption

So we finally have :
$$|A_n|=|\hat P(A_{n-1}) \times \hat P(A_{n-1})|=|A_n\times A_n|=$$

Now, the next question requires to find where the proof of this statement fails for $P(A)$ instead of $\hat P(A)$, but my proof did not use the fact we are removing the empty set anywhere, So I`m pretty sure I have a mistake.

I'd be happy if someone can correct me and offer alternative proofs.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what the question asks you for?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking perhaps one of my equality assumes axiom of choice or the continuum hypothesis but I never learnt much about them so I wouldn`t know.

Comment: Why would your equality assume things you never learned? What kind of teacher does that?

Comment: This is a proof I`ve written.I meant maybe I`ve used it without knowing.

Comment: Can you prove that $|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)|$ and $|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\setminus\{\varnothing\}|$ are the same?

Comment: Wouldn`t it be possible by just mapping {1} to $\emptyset$ , and the other singletons to {n} to {n-1} and keep the other sets as is?

Comment: Yes. So if you proved something about the *cardinality* of a set, and now you're being asked to disprove it for a set of the same cardinality. Do you see why there seem to be a problem with the question?

Comment: I understand . Thank you . Other than that, does my proof seem correct?